# Ternary operator and template literals in Angular2+ together causing issues?

Tags: angular, template-literals, angularjs-interpolate

I have a simple Angular template that is currently using string concatenation within interpolation as follows:

```
<h4>{{ myVar.property ? myVar.property + ' IS NOT NULL' : '' }}</h4>
```

What I would like to do is replace the concatenation with template literals like so:

```
<h4>{{ myVar.property ? `${myVar.property} IS NOT NULL` : '' }}</h4>
```

When trying this, I get an unexpected Lexer error. Is there some way that I can implement this ternary expression and use template strings as opposed to string concatenation?

Answer (score 2):

This feature is not available in angular and was also [rejected as a feature](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/35563):

> This has been rejected because it would not work with inline templates

Is one of the reasons. The other bigger one is that angular needs to observe `myVar.property` for changes to update the HTML accordingly. This is not possible if you just have the interpolated string there.

If you want to use template literals you need to call a function, that internally uses template literals, but IMO that would be more hassle than it would be worth.